# How to evade the lasers in world 2-Boss?

Tags: electronic-super-joy

So, I'm playing Electronic Super Joy. At the boss of the second world, a giant monster chasing you, I fail everytime because the monster shoots lasers which kill you instantly. Is there any way on not making it shoot there or evading them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boss shoots lasers when you get too close to it, and there is no way to avoid them. You need to move faster to never be near the left side of the screen.